# How to restart an update loop of an application

Tags: java, swing, game-loop

I am working on a drawing application, using Java and Swing. It has a constant update loop that runs constantly, as long as a boolean variable is set to `true`. The loop is located inside a thread.

It works fine, but now I want the loop to only run at certain times (only when the mouse is pressed), and otherwise not run. (Thus not wasting memory for nothing).

To stop the loop, I can simply set that variable to `false`. But my question is, how can I restart the loop after stopping it? Setting that variable back to `true` will not restart the loop. What would be a good way to do this?

EDIT: My (a little simplified) loop:

```
public void run(){

    int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 50;
    int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
    int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;

    long next_game_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int loops;

    boolean app_is_running = true;

    while( app_is_running ) {

        loops = 0;
        while( System.currentTimeMillis() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {

            update();

            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
        }

        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, but as far as I learned sometimes it's a problem to stop a thread, it's relatively difficult (starting it is easy of course). But theoretically, you're suggesting that I stop the thread when pausing the loop and start it when wanting to restart the loop?

Comment: Please check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop and restart a loop inside a thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087609/how-to-stop-and-restart-a-loop-inside-a-thread)

Answer (score 0):

To execute the thread body once every `FRAME_RATE` ms while being controllable by an externally defined Boolean, the `run` method could be structured as such:

```
public void run()
{
    long delay;
    long frameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // INSERT YOUR INITIALIZATION CODE HERE

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (active)  // Boolean defined outside of thread
            {
                // INSERT YOUR LOOP CODE HERE
            }

            frameStart += FRAME_RATE;
            delay = frameStart - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (delay > 0)
            {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException exception) {}
}
```

Additionally, if you want to eliminate the slight overhead of the constantly running loop (for a mostly *inactive* thread), the Boolean in the while loop could be replaced with a `Semaphore` object:

```
while (true)
{
    semaphore.acquire();  // Semaphore defined outside thread with 1 permit

    // INSERT YOUR LOOP CODE HERE 

    semaphore.release();

    frameStart += FRAME_RATE;
    delay = frameStart - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (delay > 0)
    {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

To stop the loop externally use `semaphore.acquire()`; to restart it use `semaphore.release()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.wait` to suspend the thread when it isn't running. Have another thread call `Object.notify` to wake it up from its sleep.