# How to stop and restart a loop inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm working with Java using Swing. I am working on a drawing application. It has a constant update loop that runs constantly, as long as a Boolean variable is set to `true`. The loop is located inside a thread.

It works fine, but now I want the loop to only run at certain times (only when the mouse is pressed), and otherwise not run. (Thus not wasting memory for nothing).

To stop the loop, I can simply set that variable to `false`, so the `while` loop will exit. But my question is, how can I restart the loop after stopping it? Setting that variable back to `true` will not restart the loop, because the program is already outside of that loop (am I correct?). If so, what would be a good way to do this?

My loop:

```
public void run(){

    int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 50;
    int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
    int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;

    long next_game_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int loops;

    boolean app_is_running = true;

    while( app_is_running ) {

        loops = 0;
        while( System.currentTimeMillis() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {

            update();
            catch (AWTException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
        }

        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: @NickWiggill No problem, updated the question. I'm using Java and Swing.

Comment: Haha no problem, I just deleted my comment when I saw your update in response.

Answer (score 2):

Move your loop to it's own method. Then when you need to stop you can return from the method. When you want to go back in just call the method again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have the mouse click handler spawn the thread if needed?  Use a variable to track when the thread is running so it knows not to respawn.  Simply exit the thread when you're done.  That should minimize resources when the task isn't needed.

Answer (score -1):

Use recursions. Call the loop inside itself. Or call the method inside itself.

Or you could code it into a method so you can call that loop as needed.

Comment: Recursion here will likely waste the stack.